# view the word document in axoframer

Tags: c#, ms-word

i am using axoframer control in my c# windows form application to load the ms-word document on my application. i can able to open the file successfully and also, easily navigate the file through axoframer control.

i have loaded the word document in axoframer control, intially axoframer control displayed the below mentioned error message.

"unable to display inactive document. click here to reactivate the object.".

after, clicking this line on the axoframer control, then the word document coming to visible.

the same problem occurred while maximize that form after minimized it. is this any way to refresh this document of the control? how to load a document without getting this error message.

please guide me get out of this issue...

thanks & regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    axFramerControl1.FrameHookPolicy = OfficeCtrl.ocFrameHookPolicy.ocSetOnFirstOpen;
    axFramerControl1.ActivationPolicy = OfficeCtrl.ocActivationPolicy.ocKeepUIActiveOnAppDeactive;
}
```